# How to upload photo to facebook from a camera application

Tags: android, facebook

I just used a code for camera application in android. In this application, the photo that clicked is saved in to SD Card.My code for saving as shown bellow  $

```
Camera.PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() 
    {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) 
        {
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try 
            {               
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));  
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();              
                sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED, Uri.parse("file://"+ Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
                Log.d(TAG, "on pictureTaken" + data.length);
            } 
            catch (FileNotFoundException e) 
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
            finally
            {}
            Log.d(TAG, "on pictureTaken-jpeg");                         
        }
    };
```

I just upload that image from sd card to facebook by using another activity by using FacebookSDK as shown bellow.

```
public class Upload extends Activity  implements OnItemClickListener 
{

    /* Your Facebook Application ID must be set before running this example
     * See http://www.facebook.com/developers/createapp.php
     */
    public static final String APP_ID = "146770088755283";

    private LoginButton mLoginButton;
    private TextView mText;
    private ImageView mUserPic;
    private Handler mHandler;
    ProgressDialog dialog;

    final int AUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE = 0;
    final int PICK_EXISTING_PHOTO_RESULT_CODE = 1;

    private ListView list;
    String[] main_items = {"Upload Photo"};
    String[] permissions = {"offline_access", "publish_stream", "user_photos", "publish_checkins", "photo_upload"};

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if (APP_ID == null) 
        {
            Util.showAlert(this, "Warning", "Facebook Applicaton ID must be " +
                    "specified before running this example: see FbAPIs.java");
            return;
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mHandler = new Handler();

        mText = (TextView) Upload.this.findViewById(R.id.txt);
        mUserPic = (ImageView)Upload.this.findViewById(R.id.user_pic);

        //Create the Facebook Object using the app id.
        Utility.mFacebook = new Facebook(APP_ID);
        //Instantiate the asynrunner object for asynchronous api calls.
        Utility.mAsyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(Utility.mFacebook);

        mLoginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login);

        //restore session if one exists
        SessionStore.restore(Utility.mFacebook, this);
        SessionEvents.addAuthListener(new FbAPIsAuthListener());
        SessionEvents.addLogoutListener(new FbAPIsLogoutListener());

        /*
         * Source Tag: login_tag
         */
        mLoginButton.init(this, AUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE, Utility.mFacebook, permissions);

        if(Utility.mFacebook.isSessionValid()) 
        {
            requestUserData();
        }

        list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.main_list);

        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
        list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main_list_item, main_items));
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() 
    {
        super.onResume();
        if(Utility.mFacebook != null && !Utility.mFacebook.isSessionValid())
        {
            mText.setText("You are logged out! ");
            mUserPic.setImageBitmap(null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        switch(requestCode)
        {
            /*
             * if this is the activity result from authorization flow, do a call back to authorizeCallback
             * Source Tag: login_tag
             */
            case AUTHORIZE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_CODE: 
            {
                Utility.mFacebook.authorizeCallback(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                break;
            }
            /*
             * if this is the result for a photo picker from the gallery, upload the image after scaling it.
             * You can use the Utility.scaleImage() function for scaling
             */
            case PICK_EXISTING_PHOTO_RESULT_CODE: 
            { 
                if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) 
                {
                    Uri photoUri = data.getData();
                    if(photoUri != null) {
                        Bundle params = new Bundle();
                        try 
                        {
                            params.putByteArray("photo", Utility.scaleImage(getApplicationContext(), photoUri));
                        } catch  (IOException e) 
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        params.putString("caption", "FbAPIs Sample App photo upload");
                        Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("me/photos", params, "POST", new PhotoUploadListener(), null);
                    } 
                    else
                    {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error selecting image from the gallery.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } 
                else 
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No image selected for upload.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View v, int position, long arg3) 
    {
        switch(position) 
        {

             /*
             * Source Tag: upload_photo
             * You can upload a photo from the media gallery or from a remote server
             * How to upload photo: https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/498/
             */
            case 0: 
            {
                if(!Utility.mFacebook.isSessionValid()) 
                {
                    Util.showAlert(this, "Warning", "You must first log in.");
                }
                else 
                {
                    dialog = ProgressDialog.show(Upload.this, "", getString(R.string.please_wait), true, true);
                    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                        .setTitle(R.string.gallery_title)
                        .setMessage(R.string.gallery_msg)
                        .setPositiveButton(R.string.gallery_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() 
                        {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
                            {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, (MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI));
                                startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_EXISTING_PHOTO_RESULT_CODE);
                            }

                        })
                        .setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                            public void onCancel(DialogInterface d) {
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        })
                        .show();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    /*
     * callback for the feed dialog which updates the profile status
     */
    public class UpdateStatusListener extends BaseDialogListener {
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            final String postId = values.getString("post_id");
            if (postId != null) {
                new UpdateStatusResultDialog(Upload.this, "Update Status executed", values).show();
            } else {
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No wall post made", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Facebook Error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void onCancel() {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Update status cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }

    /*
     * callback for the apprequests dialog which sends an app request to user's friends.
     */
    public class AppRequestsListener extends BaseDialogListener {
        public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "App request sent", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Facebook Error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        public void onCancel() {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "App request cancelled", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
        }
    }

    /*
     * callback for the photo upload
     */
    public class PhotoUploadListener extends BaseRequestListener {

        public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    new UploadPhotoResultDialog(Upload.this, "Upload Photo executed", response).show();
                }
            });
        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Facebook Error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    public class FQLRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {

        public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Response: " + response, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });
        }

        public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Facebook Error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

    /*
     * Callback for fetching current user's name, picture, uid.
     */
    public class UserRequestListener extends BaseRequestListener {

        public void onComplete(final String response, final Object state) {
            JSONObject jsonObject;
            try {
                jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);

                final String picURL = jsonObject.getString("picture");
                final String name = jsonObject.getString("name");
                Utility.userUID = jsonObject.getString("id");

                mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        mText.setText("Welcome " + name + "!");
                        mUserPic.setImageBitmap(Utility.getBitmap(picURL));
                    }
                });

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    }

    /*
     * The Callback for notifying the application when authorization
     *  succeeds or fails.
     */

    public class FbAPIsAuthListener implements AuthListener {

        public void onAuthSucceed() {
            requestUserData();
        }

        public void onAuthFail(String error) {
            mText.setText("Login Failed: " + error);
        }
    }

    /*
     * The Callback for notifying the application when log out
     *  starts and finishes.
     */
    public class FbAPIsLogoutListener implements LogoutListener {
        public void onLogoutBegin() {
            mText.setText("Logging out...");
        }

        public void onLogoutFinish() {
            mText.setText("You have logged out! ");
            mUserPic.setImageBitmap(null);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Request user name, and picture to show on the main screen.
     */
    public void requestUserData() {
        mText.setText("Fetching user name, profile pic...");
        Bundle params = new Bundle();
        params.putString("fields", "name, picture");
        Utility.mAsyncRunner.request("me", params, new UserRequestListener());
    }


    /**
     * Definition of the list adapter
     */
    public class MainListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;

        public MainListAdapter() {
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(Upload.this.getBaseContext());
        }

        public int getCount() {
            return main_items.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            View hView = convertView;
            if(convertView == null) {
                hView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.main_list_item, null);
                ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder();
                holder.main_list_item = (TextView) hView.findViewById(R.id.main_api_item);
                hView.setTag(holder);
            }

            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) hView.getTag();

            holder.main_list_item.setText(main_items[position]);

            return hView;
        }   

    }


    class ViewHolder {
        TextView main_list_item;
    }

}
```

I want to upload that photo to facebook without save to SD Card and from the same activity that photo clicked. If anyone knows about it, please help me....

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible in your case. The reason looks to be you are using native camera to capture a snap.So by default your snap will be saved to sdcard in the default location. There is no way you can stop it. But still you can delete the image after it is captured using the data returned from the Activity Result.